# Linux Firewall authentication based on MySQL?

Tags: firewall, iptables

I have a linux server that many users connect to. I use Squid for http access but I need a software that can grant access control to different ports based on a MySQL database.

IPtables is great but I need something that will work with MySQL and grant control based on certain IF conditions.

Thanks

Comment: Can you go into a bit more detail about what kind of authentication you are trying to implement?

Comment: It's a very simple one: IP authentication. I know IPtables allow you to set a range of allowed IP addresses. I need to do the same thing but based on a list of ip addresses in a database. In a sense, the authentication won't be done here. I just need an access control to do some Mysql query "query IP_list, if allow_IP exists, allow access; else Deny."

Comment: Have you thought about the performance issues of trying to do this?  Do you really want a mysql query run for every single packet?

Comment: You are right. Is there any way to do a transparent SOCKS proxy?

Answer (score 2):

iptables permits you to do special processing per packet, by assigning the packet to the `QUEUE` chain; each packet must then be processed by a userland program that will decide the fate of the packet (Accept, drop, et-cetera).  Writing such a handler is described here: `http://imchris.org/projects/libipq.html`.  Because this technique involves making a routing decision per-packet in userland; it may have some serious throughput implications.  If possible, you really should consider using ErikA's suggestion of just writing a script that manages rules as needed.

Answer (score 1):

IPtables/netfilter is your only option. What you'll need is some custom script that manages netfilter rules according to information in your database.

I know of nothing that can do this out of the box. You'll likely need to roll this one yourself.

Comment: Thanks Erik. My question is how to make Iptables work with MySQL. Is there a plugin?

Comment: Not that I know of, and even if there were, it would likely require a large amount of customization to get it to fit your needs.